# Printing certain variables in gdb causes execution to resume

Tags: gdb

I have been using gdb for most of a decade now and have never seen this particular problem. I upgraded to gdb 7.4 and the problem persists.

I am debugging a Cilk-multithreaded C++ application on RHEL5. Execution ceases at a seg fault. When I ask gdb to print the value of certain variables (which are boost::intrusive_ptr references to templated object instances) gdb will print the proper value, but will also *resume execution on all threads for a very short time*. I suspect it resumes execution because more of my debug print statements scroll to the terminal (it's not just clearing a buffer---I can keep printing it and it keeps resuming execution). This short spurt of continued execution causes the values of the variables I am tracking to change. This hinders debugging, to say the least.

I suspect that I have a memory leak and the stack is getting corrupted, but I've run valgrind on the code (with different initial conditions) and it shows no memory leaks in the major subsystem that I am debugging, except for a nominal Cilk-internal leak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I ask gdb to print the value of certain variables (which are boost::intrusive_ptr references to templated object instances) gdb will print the proper value, but will also resume execution on all threads for a very short time.

The only way that I know of for this to happen is if you have

1. A python pretty-printer for the type (`boost::intrusive_ptr`) and
2. That pretty-printer calls back into the inferior (being debugged) process.

You can disable all pretty-printers by e.g. `disable pretty-printer`. If that helps, you should probably figure out which exact pretty-printer is doing this, and contact its author.

Comment: I am impressed that you know this, thank you for your help. I converted all the smart pointers to standard pointers and am not experiencing many of my problems any more, but I will remember this.